# Trying to write CSV file, "Cannot access a closed file."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, csv

I am trying to write a CSV file using the NuGet CsvHelper Package.  When I run the controller action I'm seeing "Cannot access a closed file."

```
 SurveyResponseModel person = surveyResponseRepository.Get().Include(s => s.PersonModel).FirstOrDefault();

    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter("file.csv")))
    {
        csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
        csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ',';
        csv.WriteRecord(person);
    }
```

I'm not sure what is causing this.  Anybody know how I can get this to write a .CSV file?

Comment: Maybe try specifically declaring a path with the streamwriter.  
`using (var csv = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter(@"c:\file.csv")))`

Comment: Doh!  Looks like that was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to declare a specific path like:

```
  using (var csv = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter(@"c:\file.csv")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try calling

```
csv.Open()
```

first before you try writing.

Answer (score 0):

Need to us csv.Writer.WriteRecord(person)?

Answer (score 0):

Their basic example does not use a `using` statement around the `CsvWriter`.  Try removing that.  Is it possible it's trying to dispose of `CsvWriter` before it should?

https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/wiki/Basics